# How to line up the empty cells with filled cells for array of data structure?

Tags: matrices, arrays, database

I'm trying to line up the empty cells with filled cells for an array in data structure. Please help!! This is the code I have so far:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,backgrounds}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,
             nodes={draw, minimum size=8mm},
             nodes in empty cells,
             row 1/.style={nodes={draw=none}},]
{
  0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
  2 & 4 & 4 & 5 &  &  &  & &\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It comes out look like this:
[image]

I want to line up the boxes, how can I do that???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to define anchor of nodes

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,
             nodes={draw, minimum size=8mm, anchor=south},     % <-- added anchor
             column sep=-\pgflinewidth, row sep=-\pgflinewidth, % <-- for overlaps cells borders
             nodes in empty cells,
             row 1/.style={nodes={draw=none}}
             ]
{
  0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
  2 & 4 & 4 & 5 &   &   &   &   \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]